# Real time keyboard inputs in batch

Tags: batch-file

This link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eULe3DNS8DM
Shows a game made in batch. The game, called viewpoint, allows you to move around and shoot at enemies. This game seems to accept keyboard input in real time to perform actions. Is there any way I can get my batch file to accept keyboard input in real time as well?

(Guessing by the "Core" folder I saw in the game folder, there might be some other program or command involved.)

Comment: something like [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741)?

Comment: Tips: Use `for` loop to control break lines and spaces so that theplayer looks like it's moving around. E.g: If player is at line 5, and "w" key is hit (which tells to move up), `set /a previous_line=5 & set /a current_line=%previous_line%-1 & for /l %%a in (1,1,%current_line%) do echo.`

Comment: @Stephan: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the choice command (which is what `snake.bat` uses) however it can only take alpha-numeric input one at a time.

Here is a quick program I whipped up which uses `choice` to take `WASD` input.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
prompt $$$G
title movement
color 0a
set length=
for %%a in (1 2 3) do (
set "length=!length!                                                                                "
)
:controls
  cls
  echo Use WASD to move your character ([]).
  echo.
  echo %length%[]
  choice /c wasd /n
  if %errorlevel% equ 1 call:up
  if %errorlevel% equ 2 call:left
  if %errorlevel% equ 3 call:down
  if %errorlevel% equ 4 call:right

:left
  set length=!length:~0,-1!
  goto controls

:right
  set "length= %length%"
  goto controls

:up
  set length=!length:~0,-80!
  goto controls

:down
  set "length=                                                                                %length%"
  goto controls
```

The main thing you should focus on is the `:controls` label and how it uses the `choice` command to read input.